# Doubt in if/else-if logic

Tags: java

I am using the following code

```
String sample = " : : ";
String[] splitTime = sample.split(":");
if ( splitTime[0].trim().equals("") ||
        splitTime[0].trim().equals(null)) {
      System.out.println("Inside Split 0");
      splitTime[0] = "0";
 } else if (splitTime[1].trim().equals("") ||
        splitTime[1].trim().equals(null)) {
      System.out.println("Inside Split 1");
      splitTime[1] = "0";
 }else if (splitTime[2].trim().equals("") ||
        splitTime[2].trim().equals(null)) {
      System.out.println("Inside Split2");
      splitTime[2] = "0";
 }

 System.out.println("Value 1 :"+splitTime[0]);
 System.out.println("Value 2 :"+splitTime[1]);
 System.out.println("Value 3 :"+splitTime[2]);
```

OUTPUT :
Inside Split 0
Value 1 :0
Value 2 :  
Value 3 : 
I don know why it is not going into second and third if-else statement. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try to solve this using a foreach-loop: foreach (String item in splitTime) { /* do the work for each item */ }

Comment: foreach is no use here because the strings are immutable and the original values need to be overwritten, using the array index.

Answer (score 3):

It's because of the "`else if`".

If you have code that does:

```
if (a) {
} else if (b) {
}
```

Then the second branch can never be executed if the first branch was.

Instead you need:

```
if (a) {
}

if (b) {
}
```

to make the conditions independent.

BTW, `String.trim()` can't return `null`, and you're not guaranteed to get three elements in the output from `String.split()`.  Potentially better code would be:

```
String sample = " : : ";
String[] splitTime = sample.split(":");
for (int i = 0; i < splitTime.length; ++i) {
    splitTime[i] = splitTime[i].trim();
    if (splitTime[i].length() == 0) {
        splitTime[i] = "0";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

because if the first if statement is true, and thus is executed, then the rest of the else ifs are not executed. If you want to execute the other else-if statements, why not rewrite them as separate if statements?

```
String sample = "::";
String[] splitTime = sample.split(":");
if ( splitTime[0].trim().equals("") ||
        splitTime[0].trim().equals(null)) {
      System.out.println("Inside Split 0");
      splitTime[0] = "0";
 }
 if (splitTime[1].trim().equals("") ||
        splitTime[1].trim().equals(null)) {
      System.out.println("Inside Split 1");
      splitTime[1] = "0";
 } 
 if (splitTime[2].trim().equals("") ||
        splitTime[2].trim().equals(null)) {
      System.out.println("Inside Split2");
      splitTime[2] = "0";
 }

 System.out.println("Value 1 :"+splitTime[0]);
 System.out.println("Value 2 :"+splitTime[1]);
 System.out.println("Value 3 :"+splitTime[2]);
```

Comment: A standard for loop iterating over the array would be help as an alternative.

Comment: indeed that is the proper way to do what the example seemed to intend

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the fundamental operation of an If-Else clause:

```
if(foo) {
  // A
} else if(bar) {
  // B
}
```

If `foo` is true, `A` will execute, and `bar` will never be tested.  To get the semantics you want, consider just chaining your if blocks:

```
if(foo){
  // A
}

if(bar) {
  // B
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In nested if else-if statements, if one statement is executed then others are not executed. In your case, the first if expression is always true so it executes and thus other two never be executed.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
String sample = " 12 : 59 : 60 ";
// strip spaces and create up to 3 parts
String[] splitTime = sample.trim().split(" *: *", 3);
for (int i = 0; i < splitTime.length; i++)
    System.out.println("Inside " + i + " '" + splitTime[i] + '\'');
```

Prints

```
Inside 0 '12'
Inside 1 '59'
Inside 2 '60'
```