# How can split a string which contains only delimiter?

Tags: java, regex, split

I am using the following code:

```
String sample = "::";
String[] splitTime = sample.split(":");
// extra detail omitted
System.out.println("Value 1 :"+splitTime[0]);
System.out.println("Value 2 :"+splitTime[1]);
System.out.println("Value 3 :"+splitTime[2]);
```

I am getting `ArrayIndexOutofBound` exception.  How does `String.split()` handle consecutive or trailing / opening delimiters?

**See also**:

- [Doubt in split method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785533)
- [Java split() method strips empty strings at the end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545957)

Answer (score 27):

Alnitak is correct that trailing empty strings will be discarded by default.

If you want to have trailing empty strings, you should use [`split(String, int)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)) and pass a negative number as the `limit` parameter.

> The `limit` parameter controls the number of times the
>    pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting
>    array.  If the limit *n* is greater than zero then the pattern
>    will be applied at most *n* - 1 times, the array's
>    length will be no greater than *n*, and the array's last entry
>    will contain all input beyond the last matched delimiter.  If *n*
>    is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as
>    possible and the array can have any length.  If *n* is zero then
>    the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can
>    have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

Note that [`split(aString)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) is a synonym for `split(aString, 0)`:

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument `split` method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

Also, you should use a loop to get the values from the array; this avoids a possible `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

So your corrected code should be (assuming you *want* the trailing empty strings):

```
String sample = "::";
String[] splitTime = sample.split(":", -1);
for (int i = 0; i < splitTime.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Value " + i + " : \"" + splitTime[i] + "\"");
}
```

Output:

```
Value 0 : ""
Value 1 : ""
Value 2 : ""
```

Comment: good point about the -ve limit, but still requires that the array bounds are checked in case the input only had one ":" in it.

Answer (score 4):

From the [J2SE API manual](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)):

> Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

So, if you pass in "`::`" you'll get an empty array because all of the delimiters are trailing.

If you want to make sure that you get *no more* than three entries you should use:

```
String[] splitTime = sample.split(":", 3);
```

With an input of "`::`" that would indeed give you three empty strings in the output array.

However if the input only happens to have one "`:`" in it then you'll still only get two elements in your array.

Comment: using "::".split(":") actualy returns an empty array and not a two element array.

Answer (score 1):

Like this perhaps?

```
int ndx = 0;
StringTokenizer t = new StringTokenizer(": : ::::",":");
while (t.hasMoreElements())
{
    System.out.println(String.format("Value %d : %s", ++ndx,t.nextElement()));
}
```

Comment: That returns two tokens, each containing just a space.  But Raja specifically asked about strings that contain nothing but delimiters

Comment: A couple more points. 1. when you use a StringTokenizer you should always use hasMoreTokens() and nextToken(), not hasMoreElements() and nextElement(). Those are only there to flesh out the Enumeration interface. 2. There's no need to need to use String.format() the way you did; PrintStreams like System.out have their own format() methods, plus printf() methods for the traditionalists. :-)

Comment: Thanks Alan,

As you may have guessed already, java is not my primary language. However I'm trying to become more proficient with it. So I appreciate your comments.

Comment: FWIW, StringTokenizer is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function StringTokenizer in which u pass the string and the second argument as delimiter

use splittime.length function to find the length

Comment: Bad advice. StringTokenizer would treat the two colons as one delimiter. Anyway, StringTokenizer is a legacy class; developers are encouraged to use split() instead.

Comment: About using splitTime.length: in this example the length will always be zero. All of the "tokens" would have been zero-length strings, and StringTokenizer never returns empty tokens.

Answer (score 0):

you should check the length of the splitTime array.