# system.arraycopy when reading from file - java

Tags: java

I need to read data from file in the format: int, Name nameClass, String, String, String, Scores [int,int,int,int,int], for example

150, John, Smith, USA, Active, Pro, 3,4,3,4,4

After running the code I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at f1_final.CompetitorList.processLine(CompetitorList.java:184)
    at f1_final.CompetitorList.readFile(CompetitorList.java:149)
    at f1_final.FileWriterComp.main(FileWriterComp.java:14)
```

I figured out that this is due to me trying to copy int to a String. How can i go around and get this fixed?

```
private void processLine(String line)   {
    String compNo = "";

    try {
        String [] parts = line.split(",");
        nameClass compName = new nameClass(parts[1], parts[2]);
        compNo = parts[0];
        compNo = compNo.trim();


        String compCountry = parts[3];
        String compLevel = parts [4];
        String compActive = parts[5];

        int compNumber = Integer.parseInt(compNo);
        int compScoreLength = parts.length-6;
        int cScore[] = new int[compScoreLength];

        System.arraycopy(parts, 6, cScore, 0, compScoreLength);         // this line is causing problems which I wasnt able to fix. The program is unable to read arrays from file.

    //  int[]cScore = new int [compScoreLength];
    //  for(int i=0 ; i< compScoreLength ; i++)
    //          cScore[i] = parts[6].charAt(i)-'0';


        Competitor c = new Competitor(compNumber, compName, compCountry, compLevel, compActive, cScore);
        this.addOneCompetitor(c);
    }
```

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it

Comment: And you might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785586/how-can-split-a-string-which-contains-only-delimiter

Comment: `compScoreLength` is related to the number of parts, so `i` is related to the number of parts, but then `parts[6].charAt(i)` means that you believe that the *length* of the 7th parts is related to the *number* of parts? That doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

The stach trace clearly indicated an exception in `java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)`, which is called in the part you uncommented.  It seems you did not rebuild after you uncommented it.  Note that `System.arraycopy()` only works if source and target array have the same type.

You have to manually convert each element:

```
  int[]cScore = new int [compScoreLength];
  for(int i=0 ; i< compScoreLength ; i++)
          cScore[i] = Integer.parseInt(parts[6 + i]);
```

You have in this example `parts[6] = "3"`, `parts[7] = "4"`, `parts[8] = "3"`,..., all of them are a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

The [System.arraycopy()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/system_arraycopy.htm) method can copy arrays of the same type but not a string array to an integer array. You end up with an **ArrayStoreException**. You could do it this way...here is your method. I've added some data validation and defaulting:

```
private void processLine(String line) {
    /* RegEx to eliminate the need for trim after parsing. 
       Handles all comma/space situations.   */
    String splitExp = "\\s{0,},\\s{0,}";

    // Split the file line into a string array.
    String[] parts = line.split(splitExp);

    // Make sure the CompNo is a string integer numerical value
    if (!parts[0].matches("\\d+")) {
        System.err.println("Invalid 'Comp Number' Detected!");
        return;  // exit this method.
    }
    int compNumber = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]); // parts[0] is obviously valid

    if (parts[1].equals("") || parts[2].equals("")) {
        System.err.println("Invalid 'Name' Components Detected!");
        return;  // exit this method.
    }

    /* 'Ternary Operator' is used to ensure a default is 
       used if name elements are invalid.       */
    nameClass compName = new nameClass(
            (parts[1].equals("") ? "UNKNOWN" : parts[1]),
            (parts[2].equals("") ? "UNKNOWN" : parts[2])
            );

    /* Again, 'Ternary Operator' is used to ensure a default 
       is used if elements are invalid.       */
    String compCountry = parts[3].equals("") ? "UNKNOWN" : parts[3];
    String compLevel = parts[4].equals("") ? "UNKNOWN" : parts[4];
    String compActive = parts[5].equals("") ? "UNKNOWN" : parts[5];

    // Get Scores - Create and fill a cScore integer array.
    int[] cScore = new int[parts.length - 6];
    for (int i = 6; i < parts.length; i++) {
        // Is this a valid score number
        if (!parts[i].matches("\\d+")) {
            System.err.println("The #" + (i + 1) + " score value ("
                    + parts[i] + ") is not a valid score number! "
                    + "0 will be used in its place!");
            /* Because i started a index 6 we subract 6 
               from i to get the true required index value
               for cScore       */
            cScore[i-6] = 0; 
        }
        else {
            /* Only valid string representations of integer 
               values will pass through here.            */
            cScore[i-6] = Integer.parseInt(parts[i]);
        }
    }

    Competitor c = new Competitor(compNumber, compName, compCountry, compLevel, compActive, cScore);
    this.addOneCompetitor(c);
}
```